# Can multiple binary messengers/ method channels send messages across the same channel name?

Tags: flutter-plugin

I am trying to share MethodChannels between dart isolates, so that an `invokeMethod` called on the platform side is called on both isolates (e.g. the Root isolate and a new isolate I created)?

We could for example, instantiate the MethodChannel (and associated `BinaryMessenger`) in both isolates, and also on the platform/ host side.

Warning: the binary messenger docs states:

> BinaryMessenger is expected to be utilized from a single thread throughout the duration of its existence.

In the docs of `MethodChannel` though:

> The logical identity of the channel is given by its name. Identically named channels **will interfere with each other's communication.**

Unfortunately, my new isolate doesn't seem to reach the platform when it sends its messages: I get `No implementation found for method MethodName on channel com.example.app.package`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Yes, the methods were actually being called.

It was working. This was a **bad** idea, but the actual method was being called: the 2 Method Channels on dart side and 2 method channels on Platform side were calling each other just fine. They all had the same channel name. Probably **not** a good idea for complexity reasons (see below), but *it worked*.  Problems:

- Only **one** method call handler was called. I created two on the recipient side, but only one of the method call handlers were called. Not good.

If you have separate components on your app (Android components: Activity, Service, Broadcast Receiver or Dart Isolates):

- Use **unique channel names** for the `MethodChannel` to keep things sane. If you share the same channel name between different method call handlers (components in your app), you will have to stop using `result.notImplemented`, which is a safety guard.
- If you're thinking about 2 method channels, you might also be thinking about 0 initially, or optional method calls, where the platform doesn't currently have a valid method channel for that channel name. If you don't have one instantiated yet, an error will be thrown: `No implementation found for method $methodName on channel $name`.

  - Use `try { /* ... */ } on MissingPluginException { /* ignore */ }` to ignore exceptions when you know your method channel isn't ready (or even instantiated) yet on the Android side.

### My specific issue:

The reason I was getting `No implementation found for method MethodName` was exactly because I had **two** MethodChannels on the dart side, and **two** on Platform side. I was recreating the same isolate, so I had 2 Flutter applications running **simultaneously**. When one Isolate called a dart method I did not implement on on Method Call Handler on Platform side, I got this error.